# Loop won't stop with Thread and CancellationToken

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, windows-socket-api

I'm working with a Windows socket application using async callbacks. If I use Thread to start `_StartListening`, when I call `StopListening`, the loop still stops at `allDone.WaitOne()`. But the Task version will be OK.

What's the difference?

My code is a modified version of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)

The original version with `ManualResetEvent` has a race condition mentioned by [felix-b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368809/9389566). I changed it to `SemaphoreSlim` but the problem is still there.

I tried in debug mode and it seems that the break point never be hit at `if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)` after I call `StopListening` even I don't start the client.

Sorry. I found that I accidentally started two socket servers. That's the problem.

```cs
  class WinSocketServer:IDisposable
  {
        public SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            semaphore.Release();
            //Do something
        }

        private void _StartListening(CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),listener);
                    semaphore.Wait();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Complete");
        }
        public void StartListening()
        {
            Task.Run(() => _StartListening(cancelSource.Token));//OK

            var t = new Thread(() => _StartListening(cancelSource.Token));
            t.Start();//Can't be stopped by calling StopListening
        }

        public void StopListening()
        {
            listener.Close();
            cancelSource.Cancel();
            semaphore.Release();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            StopListening();
            cancelSource.Dispose();
            semaphore.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit of a convoluted setup.  Perhaps consider using SemaphoreSlim instead.  Or if not, good luck :D

Comment: Your thread(s) may all be waiting at `allDone.WaitOne()` when the cancellation is requested. Probably not the best synchronisation approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a race condition that can lead to deadlock (sometimes). Let's name the threads "listener" (one that runs `_StartListening`) and "control" (one that runs `StopListening`):

1. Listener thread: `if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)` -> false
2. Control thread: `cancelSource.Cancel()`
3. Control thread: `allDone.Set()`
4. Listener thread: `allDone.Reset()` -> accidentally resets the stop request!
5. Listener thread: `listener.BeginAccept(...)`
6. Control thread: `stopListening()` exits, while the listener continues to work!
7. Listener thread: `allDone.WaitOne()` -> deadlock! no one will do `allDone.Set()`.

The problem is in how you use the `allDone` event, it should be the other way around: `_StartListening` should do `allDone.Set()` just before it exits for whatever reason, whereas `StopListening` should do `allDone.WaitOne()`:

```cs
class WinSocketServer:IDisposable
{
    // I guess this was in your code, necessary to show proper stopping
    private Socket listener = new Socket(......); 

    public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private void _StartListening(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        try
        {
            listener.Listen(...); // I guess 
            allDone.Reset(); // reset once before starting the loop
            while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),listener);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        allDone.Set(); // notify that the listener is exiting
        Console.WriteLine("Complete");
    }
    public void StartListening()
    {
        Task.Run(() => _StartListening(cancelSource.Token));
    }
    public void StopListening()
    {
        // notify the listener it should exit
        cancelSource.Cancel(); 
        // cancel possibly pending BeginAccept
        listener.Close();
        // wait until the listener notifies that it's actually exiting
        allDone.WaitOne();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        StopListening();
        cancelSource.Dispose();
        allDone.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

It worth noting that `listener.BeginAccept` won't return until there is a new client connection. When stopping the listener, it is necessary to close the socket (`listener.Close()`) to force `BeginAccept` to exit.

The difference in Thread/Task behavior is really weird, it probably can originate from the Task thread being a background thread, while the regular thread being a foreground one.

Comment: Well I actually modified the example code on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example).  Hmm I think there's no race condition since the 'Set' and 'WaitOne' are paired. Maybe it's my fault to omit the 'Set' code in the callback.

Comment: You can post the code of the callback for the more complete answer. The race condition is there regardless what the callback does, though. Try passing through the steps I listed in the answer.

Comment: You are right. I'll fix it. But the thread is blocked even if I don't start the client when I start the ‘ _StartListening’ with Thread not Task. That's weird.

Comment: Note that in the answer, I added 'listener.Close()' that forces BeginAccept to exit, otherwise it would block until a new client connection -- see the update.

Comment: Sorry. I add it to my code but I forget to add it in the description :p